# Check if string contains characters in certain order in C#r

Tags: c#, string, file, character

I have a code that's working right now, but it doesn't check if the characters are in order, it only checks if they're there. How can I modify my code so the the characters 'gaoaf' are checked in that order in the string?

```
Console.WriteLine("5.feladat");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("keres.txt");
            sw.WriteLine("gaoaf");
            string s = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                s = zadatok[i].nev+zadatok[i].cim;
                if (s.Contains("g") && s.Contains("a") && s.Contains("o") && s.Contains("a") && s.Contains("f") )
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(i);
                    sw.WriteLine(zadatok[i].nev + zadatok[i].cim);
                }

            }
            sw.Close();
```

Comment: Why do you not use `s.Contains("gaoaf")`?

Comment: if you want to find `gaoaf` then you can just pass that to the string.Contains() method. Or would you want to find "n**g**pw**a**r**o**s**a**tg**f**"

Comment: I'm searching for songs that contain these letters in this order. Will typing s.Contains("gaoaf") work if the whole song is for example: Omega: Ortaf?

Comment: no, which is why I asked. This is probably a job for regex or you're going to be looking at substringing and searching for the next letter only after a previous letter is found and that is going to get tricky when you are coding to handle different strings.

Comment: If `s` is "Omega: Ortaf", then it doesn't contain "gaoaf" in order unless you are ignoring case, which your sample code doesn't appear to?

Comment: It does contain the characters in order. Ome G A   O rt A F

Comment: You might also specify if this is a specific string or will the string to compare be variable? In other words is this ALWAYS looking for 'gaoaf' or will you later need to search for another group of characters?

Comment: It is always looking for gaoaf. I have a list of a bunch of songs and the task our teacher gave us was to search the songs that have these characters in them but they must be in this exact order.

Comment: OK, then I would start by converting the string to lower-case so that's not an issue. Then use indexOf to find the first letter. From that you need to then look for the next letter AFTER the index  where you found the first letter. Contains will search from the beginning to the end of the string and I don't think there's a startindex overload without checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the letters into a pattern and use `Regex`:

```
var letters = "gaoaf";
var pattern = String.Join(".*",letters.AsEnumerable());

var hasletters = Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

For those that needlessly avoid `.*`, you can also solve this with LINQ:

```
var ans = letters.Aggregate(0, (p, c) => p >= 0 ? s.IndexOf(c.ToString(), p, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) : p) != -1;
```

If it is possible to have repeated adjacent letters, you need to complicate the LINQ solution slightly:

```
var ans = letters.Aggregate(0, (p, c) => {
        if (p >= 0) {
            var newp = s.IndexOf(c.ToString(), p, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            return newp >= 0 ? newp+1 : newp;
        }
        else
            return p;
    }) != -1;
```

Given the (ugly) machinations required to basically terminate `Aggregate` early, and given the (ugly and inefficient) syntax required to use an inline anonymous expression call to get rid of the temporary `newp`, I created some extensions to help, an `Aggregate` that can terminate early:

```
public static TAccum AggregateWhile<TAccum, T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, TAccum seed, Func<TAccum, T, TAccum> accumFn, Predicate<TAccum> whileFn) {
    using (var e = src.GetEnumerator()) {
        if (!e.MoveNext())
            throw new Exception("At least one element required by AggregateWhile");
        var ans = accumFn(seed, e.Current);
        while (whileFn(ans) && e.MoveNext())
            ans = accumFn(ans, e.Current);
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Now you can solve the problem fairly easily:

```
var ans2 = letters.AggregateWhile(-1,
                                  (p, c) => s.IndexOf(c.ToString(), p+1, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase),
                                  p => p >= 0
                                 ) != -1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @AnettBarát If this is for homework, I suggest you ensure you thoroughly understand what this code is doing, or come up with your own method.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this?

```
static bool CheckInOrder(string source, string charsToCheck)
{
    int index = -1;
    foreach (var c in charsToCheck)
    {
        index = source.IndexOf(c, index + 1);
        if (index == -1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can use the function like this:

```
bool result = CheckInOrder("this is my source string", "gaoaf");
```

This should work because `IndexOf` returns `-1` if a string isn't found, and it only starts scanning AFTER the previous match.

Comment: was kind of hoping to let the op work out their assignment based on instructions but this is exactly what I was pushing toward.